# Type Theory Lean 3 to Lean 4

Tags: lean, type-theory, lean4, lean3, lean-mathlib

I'm aware of Lean's type theory. Did the type theory of lean change at all as we moved to Lean 4? Are there any references to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things changed but the type theory stayed exactly the same, so e.g. https://github.com/digama0/lean-type-theory/releases/tag/v1.0 is still a valid reference (edit: apparently this is not completely correct -- see Sebastian's comment below)

Comment: It is not exactly the same, the major additions are primitive projections, eta for structures, and primitive mutual inductive types. My PhD thesis, which should be available some time next month, gives more details.

Comment: @SebastianUllrich Given that Kevin’s answer is slightly wrong, it wouldn’t be bad for you to make your own short answer with what you just said.  It also wouldn’t hurt to add a line about if the changes are conservative (in that you can still prove the same theorems) and if there is an automatic way to translate Lean 3 kernel-level proofs to Lean 4 (which I assume there is given the early work on the mathlib port which translated the kernel-level proofs).

Comment: @SebastianUllrich How can I read your thesis when it is complete? Are these the only additions that were made? And how would these affect me working in Lean?

Answer (score 4):

As already [commented by Sebastian Ullrich](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/2153/type-theory-lean-3-to-lean-4#comment4756_2155), there are a few small changes to the Lean 4 kernel, detailed in [his PhD thesis](https://lean-lang.org/papers/thesis-sebastian.pdf).  Now, that it is done (and has been for a few months), I want to make sure it gets the attention it deserves.  The details on the kernel are in [Section 3.2](https://lean-lang.org/papers/thesis-sebastian.pdf#section.3.2).

Comment: Thank you, Jason. Would you recommend I read his entire thesis?

Comment: @AlexByard I’m not sure I’ve ever recommended one read a thesis, and TBH  I haven’t read Sebastian’s.  That being said, it looks, from the bits I’ve skimmed, well organized, so at least skimming it would give you a lot of information.